# How can I get jQuery to ignore parents on .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample code:

```
<div id="a">
     <div id="b">
          Click here
     </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('*').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));                    
    });
</script>
```

When you click 'Click Here' it alerts **twice**, once with '**b**' and then with '**a**'.

I need to figure out how to get jQuery to **ignore all the parents** of where the user clicked and just alert, in this case, 'b'.

Comment: I think you *should* be using `$('#a').delegate('*', 'click', function () {})` instead of attaching a click handler to `'*'` **Edit:** and actually *relying* on event bubbling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('body').delegate('*', 'click', fn)` instead of direct event handlers. (See [jQuery.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).) It will be called exactly once for each event, and you can find out from the event object which element was affected.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
  $('*').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // do something
    });
```

Here you can find documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Place your alert right after this line:
`e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "All Selector" http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

I think you are looking for this:

```
$('#b').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Comment: No, I want everything on the page to be clickable, much like when you are using Firebug and you use the 'Click an element to view source' feature.

Comment: This would also work, assuming your element's `id` will always be **b**.

Answer (score 1):

Use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('*').click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Works great for .click() -- doesn't seem to work for .hover() -- is there a way to do that for hover as well?