# Avoiding click event on absolute positioned element below

Tags: jquery, css, onclicklistener

I have 2 elements a parent element and its child, and both are absolutely positioned.

I have a click handler for each element, although when I click the child element the parent element behind it also catches the click.

How do I prevent the parent element from receiving the click event?

Comment: Can you add a JS fiddle with your code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a pure CSS solution, you could use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events). This will make sure your mouse ignores the parent element, for good, so be careful in your use of it.

Also note this is [NOT SUPPORTED](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) in IE or Opera. (Or at least, not on HTML elements, just SVG)

jQuery alternative is e.StopPropagation, more info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606536/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-ignore-parents-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery and simple have a `preventDefault` or `return false` on the parent element:

```
$('#parent').click(function() {
    return false;
});

$('#child').click(function() {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the parent from receiving a click event, it just doesn't do anything when such an event occurs. So if the OP needed to do something for a click on the parent that isn't directly on the child this wouldn't help.